# Assigning values to subset of an array defined by multiple conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to assign values to part of an array which is specified by multiple conditions.

For example:

```
    import numpy as np
    temp = np.arange(120).reshape((2,3,4,5))
    mask = temp > 22
    submask = temp[mask] < 43
    (temp[mask])[submask] = 0 # assign zeros to the part of the array specified via mask and submask
    print(temp) # notice that temp is unchanged - I want it to be changed
```

This example is artificial. Generally I want to do something more complex which involves a combination of indexing and boolean masks. Using a list index fails in similar circumstances. For example: `temp[:,:,0,[1,3,2]]=0` is a valid assignment, but `temp[:,:,0,[1,3,2]][mask]=0` will fail.

My understanding is that the assignment is failing because the complex indexing is prompting numpy to make a copy of the array object and assigning to that, rather than to the original array. So it isn't that the assignment is failing per se, just that the assignment is directed towards the "wrong" object.

I have tried using functions such as `np.copyto` and `np.putmask` but these also fail, presumably because the backend implementation mimics the original problem. For example: `np.putmask(temp, mask, 0)` will work but `np.putmask(temp[mask], submask, 0)` will not.

Is there a good way to do what I want to do?

Comment: Why not `temp[(temp>22) & (temp<43)] = 0`?

Comment: @QuangHoang my real issue is that I want to assign to a masked array that I have indexed using a list of indices (the indices are derived from a dict which links variable names to columns). However, I tried to avoid giving an overly-complex example.... the example I've given is deliberately simplified and my instinct is that a solution for that will lead directly to a solution for the real problem.

Comment: You are correct that an obvious solution is to combine the masks. I guess I'm looking for a method to solve `temp[:,:,0,[1,3,2]][mask]=0`